# $.get is not a function

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I want to get some data over JS and therefore I "develop" a small script. Actually I haven't worked with JS/JQuery for a long time and now I'm facing a very basic problem. I tried to replace the `$` with `jQuery` but I got the same error.

HTML

```
<html>
<head>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-3.1.1.slim.min.js"</script>"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="main.js"</script>"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <button>Test</button>
</body>
```

JS

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
    jQuery("button").click(function(){
        jQuery.get("mydomain", function(data, status){
            alert("Data: " + data + "\nStatus: " + status);
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: I'm pretty sure the slim releases of jQuery 3 do not include the AJAX routines. Use the full release instead.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

You are referencing jQuery Slim, which doesn't include (among other things) the Ajax functions such as `.get()`.

You need to reference the full version of jQuery instead.

See this link for more a detailed description of what is and is not included in the Slim build: https://blog.jquery.com/2016/06/09/jquery-3-0-final-released/

Answer (score 3):

Can you please try with any other version of jQuery instead of slim version?
Like this CDN:
https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js

May be ajax utilities are not available in slim version.